# Authentication failed when trying to download azure API Management locally

Tags: git, azure-api-management, ibm-api-management

I am trying to download the Azure API Management Repository locally using Git Bash following he steps on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-configuration-repository-git.

The problem is that I keep getting the "Authentication failed" even though I have doubled checked the generated password multiple times.

Steps I did to download the REPO:

1. Saved the service config to the git repo.
2. Got the access credentials.
3. Tried to clone the repo locally first by using the unencode password and after that using the encoded one. (encoded it in terminal using echo "myPass" | base64  )

I did this multiple times by generating multiple passwords, same result: authentication failed

```
 git clone https://user:encodedPasswordInBase64@myDomain.scm.azure-api.net
```

Are there any user rights that I am supposed to have in order to do this successfully?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I managed to make it work was by only providing the username to the git clone command:

```
git clone https://user@myDomain.scm.azure-api.net
```

Once I did that, a login pop up appeared and I was able to insert my password unencoded, managing to clone it.

So from my point of view it might be a documentation error since adding the encoded password did not work. I have to mention that I encoded the password because the git bash stated that some of the passwords characters were not allowed in there